# send key() does not work properly in this webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried to login username and password on [this site](https://land.copernicus.vgt.vito.be/PDF/portal/Application.html?fbclid=IwAR2_eEozlcs-Scmi9Yg__eMIwMEElT29LCj3UOtN2Oz1p0-oVHzD2VlTFBs#Browse;Root=512260;Collection=48403119;Time=NORMAL,NORMAL,-1,,,-1,,)
What i have done is just only filling password, but the error occurs when passing username.

```
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")   
driver.get("link")
time.sleep(5)

#press login button
submit=driver.find_element_by_class_name('gwt-Anchor').click()

#fill password
password_login = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password_login.send_keys("Tossawon1#")

#fill user
user_login = driver.find_element_by_name("login")

user_login.send_keys("tossawon")


> Error: "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable 
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)"
```

Result : I cannot fill user name

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your code here instead of an image.

Comment: What you want to scrap from this website?

Comment: Thank you very much, that's why, the problem is about the input type.                               
I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code you are missing type of both the username(`type='TEXT'`) and password(`type='PASSWORD'`) inputs that's why it is giving you `element not interactable` error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def mimic_login():

url = 'https://land.copernicus.vgt.vito.be/PDF/portal/Application.html?fbclid=IwAR2_eEozlcs-Scmi9Yg__eMIwMEElT29LCj3UOtN2Oz1p0-oVHzD2VlTFBs#Browse;Root=512260;Collection=48403119;Time=NORMAL,NORMAL,-1,,,-1,,'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
print("Opening Chrome Browser..")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)
wait_for_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 200)
wait_for_element.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'gwt-Anchor')))
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('gwt-Anchor').click()

wait_for_element.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"][@type="TEXT"]').send_keys('YOLO')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"][@type="PASSWORD"]').send_keys('1234567')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-button"]').click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.quit()

mimic_login()
```

Tip and points to remember:

1. Always use element to be located which will wait till that element is available for use. You can do it using `expected_conditions` of selenium.
2. Explicitly add wait time using `time.sleep` or `WebDriver.wait`. By using them you will never ran in to errors.